# How do I create a PHP SoapParam of SoapParams?

Tags: php, soap-client

I am using SoapClient to interact with http://weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl
and calling NDFDgenByDay() works fine, no problems, but when I want to call NDFDgen() I have to use curl instead because I can't figure out how to pass weatherParameters to NDFDgen() when using SoapClient.  Here is what I have tried:

```
...
$this->client =
    new SoapClient(
        'http://weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl',
        array('cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE)
    );
...
$this->xml =
    $this->client->NDFDgen(
        new SoapParam($this->latitude,  'latitude'),
        new SoapParam($this->longitude,'longitude'),
        new SoapParam('time-series',   'product'),
        new SoapParam($startTime,       'startTime'),
        new SoapParam($endTime,     'startTime'),
        new SoapParam('e',             'Unit'),
        new SoapParam(
            array(
                new SoapParam(false,'maxt'),        new SoapParam(false,'mint'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'temp'),        new SoapParam(true, 'dew'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'pop12'),       new SoapParam(true, 'qpf'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'sky'),         new SoapParam(true, 'snow'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'wspd'),        new SoapParam(true, 'wdir'),        //10
                new SoapParam(false,'wx'),          new SoapParam(false,'waveh'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'icons'),       new SoapParam(true, 'rh'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'appt'),        new SoapParam(false,'incw34'),
                new SoapParam(false,'incw50'),      new SoapParam(false,'incw64'),
                new SoapParam(false,'cumw34'),      new SoapParam(false,'cumw50'),      //20
                new SoapParam(false,'cumw64'),      new SoapParam(false,'critfireo'),
                new SoapParam(false,'dryfireo'),    new SoapParam(false,'conhazo'),
                new SoapParam(false,'ptornado'),    new SoapParam(false,'phail'),
                new SoapParam(false,'ptstmwinds'),  new SoapParam(false,'pxtornado'),
                new SoapParam(false,'pxhail'),      new SoapParam(false,'pxtstmwinds'), //30
                new SoapParam(false,'ptotsvrtstm'), new SoapParam(false,'pxtotsvrtstm'),
                new SoapParam(false,'tmpabv14d'),   new SoapParam(false,'tmpblw14d'),
                new SoapParam(false,'tmpabv30d'),   new SoapParam(false,'tmpblw30d'),
                new SoapParam(false,'tmpabv90d'),   new SoapParam(false,'tmpblw90d'),
                new SoapParam(false,'prcpabv14d'),  new SoapParam(false,'prcpblw14d'),  //40
                new SoapParam(false,'prcpabv30d'),  new SoapParam(false,'prcpblw30d'),
                new SoapParam(false,'prcpabv90d'),  new SoapParam(false,'prcpblw90d'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'precipa_r'),   new SoapParam(true, 'sky_r'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'temp_r'),      new SoapParam(true, 'td_r'),
                new SoapParam(true, 'wdir_r'),      new SoapParam(true, 'wspd_r'),      //50
                new SoapParam(true, 'wwa'),         new SoapParam(true, 'wgust')
            ),
            'weatherParameters'
        )
    );
```

There error I get is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'maxt' property in [Redacted]\data\WeatherService.php:199
```

Here is the xml that works via curl:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ndf="http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ndf:NDFDgen soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <latitude xsi:type="xsd:decimal">{$this->latitude}</latitude>
         <longitude xsi:type="xsd:decimal">{$this->longitude}</longitude>
         <product xsi:type="xsd:string">time-series</product>
         <startTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">{$this->startTime}</startTime>
         <endTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">{$this->endTime}</endTime>
         <Unit xsi:type="xsd:string">e</Unit>
         <weatherParameters xsi:type="ndf:weatherParametersType">
            <!--You may enter the following 52 items in any order-->
            <maxt xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</maxt>
            <mint xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</mint>
            <temp xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</temp>
            <dew xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</dew>
            <pop12 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</pop12>
            <qpf xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</qpf>
            <sky xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sky>
            <snow xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</snow>
            <wspd xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wspd>
            <wdir xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wdir>
            <wx xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</wx>
            <waveh xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</waveh>
            <icons xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</icons>
            <rh xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</rh>
            <appt xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</appt>
            <incw34 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</incw34>
            <incw50 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</incw50>
            <incw64 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</incw64>
            <cumw34 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</cumw34>
            <cumw50 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</cumw50>
            <cumw64 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</cumw64>
            <critfireo xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</critfireo>
            <dryfireo xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</dryfireo>
            <conhazo xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</conhazo>
            <ptornado xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ptornado>
            <phail xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</phail>
            <ptstmwinds xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ptstmwinds>
            <pxtornado xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</pxtornado>
            <pxhail xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</pxhail>
            <pxtstmwinds xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</pxtstmwinds>
            <ptotsvrtstm xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ptotsvrtstm>
            <pxtotsvrtstm xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</pxtotsvrtstm>
            <tmpabv14d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpabv14d>
            <tmpblw14d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpblw14d>
            <tmpabv30d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpabv30d>
            <tmpblw30d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpblw30d>
            <tmpabv90d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpabv90d>
            <tmpblw90d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpblw90d>
            <prcpabv14d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpabv14d>
            <prcpblw14d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpblw14d>
            <prcpabv30d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpabv30d>
            <prcpblw30d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpblw30d>
            <prcpabv90d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpabv90d>
            <prcpblw90d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpblw90d>
            <precipa_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</precipa_r>
            <sky_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sky_r>
            <temp_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</temp_r>
            <td_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</td_r>
            <wdir_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wdir_r>
            <wspd_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wspd_r>
            <wwa xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wwa>
            <wgust xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wgust>
         </weatherParameters>
      </ndf:NDFDgen>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So basically, I'd like to use SoapClient for all Soap interactions, but I don't know how to do complex parameters like the weatherParameters parameter above, if weatherParameters can be specified when using SoapClient, please show me how, because the alternative, using curl, literally adds over 100 extra lines of code to my php, between making the soap envelope and initializing and using curl, and then parsing the response xml out of the response envelope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found the solution.

This part of the request:

```
...
<weatherParameters xsi:type="ndf:weatherParametersType">
    <!--You may enter the following 52 items in any order-->
    <maxt xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</maxt>
    <mint xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</mint>
    <temp xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</temp>
    <dew xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</dew>
    <pop12 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</pop12>
    <qpf xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</qpf>
    <sky xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sky>
    <snow xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</snow>
    <wspd xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wspd>
    <wdir xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wdir>
    <wx xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</wx>
    <waveh xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</waveh>
    <icons xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</icons>
    <rh xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</rh>
    <appt xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</appt>
    <incw34 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</incw34>
    <incw50 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</incw50>
    <incw64 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</incw64>
    <cumw34 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</cumw34>
    <cumw50 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</cumw50>
    <cumw64 xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</cumw64>
    <critfireo xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</critfireo>
    <dryfireo xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</dryfireo>
    <conhazo xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</conhazo>
    <ptornado xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ptornado>
    <phail xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</phail>
    <ptstmwinds xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ptstmwinds>
    <pxtornado xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</pxtornado>
    <pxhail xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</pxhail>
    <pxtstmwinds xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</pxtstmwinds>
    <ptotsvrtstm xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ptotsvrtstm>
    <pxtotsvrtstm xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</pxtotsvrtstm>
    <tmpabv14d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpabv14d>
    <tmpblw14d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpblw14d>
    <tmpabv30d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpabv30d>
    <tmpblw30d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpblw30d>
    <tmpabv90d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpabv90d>
    <tmpblw90d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</tmpblw90d>
    <prcpabv14d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpabv14d>
    <prcpblw14d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpblw14d>
    <prcpabv30d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpabv30d>
    <prcpblw30d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpblw30d>
    <prcpabv90d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpabv90d>
    <prcpblw90d xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</prcpblw90d>
    <precipa_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</precipa_r>
    <sky_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sky_r>
    <temp_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</temp_r>
    <td_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</td_r>
    <wdir_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wdir_r>
    <wspd_r xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wspd_r>
    <wwa xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wwa>
    <wgust xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</wgust>
</weatherParameters>
...
```

Has to be converted into an Object (Struct):

```
class weatherParameters {
    function weatherParameters() {
        $this->maxt     = false;    $this->mint     = false;
        $this->temp     = true;     $this->dew          = true;
        $this->pop12        = true;     $this->qpf          = true;
        $this->sky          = true;     $this->snow     = true;
        $this->wspd     = true;     $this->wdir     = true;
        $this->wx           = false;    $this->waveh        = false;
        $this->icons        = true;     $this->rh           = true;
        $this->appt     = true;     $this->incw34       = false;
        $this->incw50       = false;    $this->incw64       = false;
        $this->cumw34       = false;    $this->cumw50       = false;
        $this->cumw64       = false;    $this->critfireo    = false;
        $this->dryfireo = false;    $this->conhazo      = false;
        $this->ptornado = false;    $this->phail        = false;
        $this->ptstmwinds   = false;    $this->pxtornado    = false;
        $this->pxhail       = false;    $this->pxtstmwinds  = false;
        $this->ptotsvrtstm  = false;    $this->pxtotsvrtstm= false;
        $this->tmpabv14d    = false;    $this->tmpblw14d    = false;
        $this->tmpabv30d    = false;    $this->tmpblw30d    = false;
        $this->tmpabv90d    = false;    $this->tmpblw90d    = false;
        $this->prcpabv14d   = false;    $this->prcpblw14d   = false;
        $this->prcpabv30d   = false;    $this->prcpblw30d   = false;
        $this->prcpabv90d   = false;    $this->prcpblw90d   = false;
        $this->precipa_r    = true;     $this->sky_r        = true;
        $this->temp_r       = true;     $this->td_r     = true;
        $this->wdir_r       = true;     $this->wspd_r       = true;
        $this->wwa          = true;     $this->wgust        = true;
    }
}
```

I hard coded the values, but you can make the values dynamic if needs be.  Then I instantiate the struct:

```
$wParameters = new weatherParameters();
```

Then I tell SoapClient how to convert that object into an XML fragment:

```
$weatherParameters = new SoapVar(
    // object to convert,encoding,name to give the object, name space definition
    $wParameters, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'weatherParameters', 'http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl'
);
```

Then you pass the SoapVar into the function call as a SoapParam:

```
$this->xml =
    $this->client->NDFDgen(
        new SoapParam($this->latitude,  'latitude'),
        new SoapParam($this->longitude,'longitude'),
        new SoapParam('time-series',   'product'),
        new SoapParam($startTime,       'startTime'),
        new SoapParam($endTime,     'startTime'),
        new SoapParam('e',             'Unit'),
        new SoapParam($weatherParameters,'weatherParameters')
    );
```

So to figure this out, I had to read all the PHP Soap... documentation, and then when I got to the documentation on SoapVar http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php, the example in SoapVar showed how it is used with SoapParam, in my opinion the examples in SoapParam http://php.net/manual/en/soapparam.soapparam.php should also illustrate the relationship between SoapVar and SoapParam better, otherwise, you may not figure out that you need a SoapVar to create a complex SoapParam.  There are 7 mentions/links of SoapVar in SoapParam doc but none of them point out that argument 1 of SoapParam would be an instance of SoapVar when you need SoapParam to represent a complex object.